# fish shell tab completion program short description - howto?

Tags: python, autocomplete, fish

With fish shell there is (among many others) a nice feature that displays a short description of the possible commands, like that:

[image]

How can I write such a description for my own commands? Specifically I would like to do that for python console_scripts.

10x.

Comment: Did any of our answers solve your problem? If so, please mark the best answer as solution. If not, expand your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add such descriptions to your Fish functions, such as this [example from VirtualFish's `activate` sub-command](https://github.com/justinmayer/virtualfish/blob/master/virtualfish/virtual.fish#L44):

```
function __vf_activate --description "Activate a virtualenv"
    […]
end
```

You can see the resulting output when typing `vf` and then the Tab key:

[image: Descriptions of VirtualFish sub-commands]

Comment: Thank you. Is this the only source where Fish takes the description from? I see descriptions for programs that do not seem to be a Fish functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the nifty completions built-in.

`complete -c mm -s i -f --description 'Interactive mode'`
This will output:
`mm -i (Interactive mode)`

Here is the official documentation:https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/complete.html

And here is a good guide on it:
https://medium.com/@fabioantunes/a-guide-for-fish-shell-completions-485ac04ac63c

I've just went through the learning process on this while creating a plugin myself, so you can take a look at how I've done it for MakeMeFish as well here: https://github.com/OakNinja/MakeMeFish/tree/next-release

Edit:
You can create completions for *any* command, fish or not, with the completion framework. There is loads of built-in completions in fish, which you can look into on github. See here: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/tree/master/share/completions